# Add an aspx page with code-behind to a compiled ASP.Net site

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an ASP.Net application, done by a third-party, that uses third-party controls. The problem is that some of these controls don't work with anything higher than IE8. I have been asked to look into this and try to figure out a way to make them work again (the company is upgrading to IE11).

Unfortunately, the source code is not available; there are no code-behind that I can work on. And the controls are no longer supported.

One solution that I can think of is adding a new .aspx page and use inline code/javascript/code-behind to return the functionalities that are not working.

This is my question: is this feasible? Or are there any other ways that I can resolve this, short of replacing the application with a new one?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" for your .aspx page to look for the code instead of CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" which will look into compiled .dll file, as a solution. However, this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a while ago and resolved it by decompiling the controls via a decompiler tool like .NET Reflector, making the necessary changes, recompiling and uploading back to the server.